# Integrating local JSON style into mapbox.js map (and filtering more than 100 polygons in Mapbox)

Tags: json, polygon, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using filters in Mapbox Studio to style a geoJSON file with 189 polygons. I was able to filter my data to create layers, but it only recognized 100 of my polygons. I did some research and saw that in fact, Studio can only process 100. I am using this style to integrate into a mapbox.js map (I was able to do so), but was unable to format the remaining 89 polygons due to the filter problem. I downloaded the JSON of this map. Could I just manually add the remaining layers into the JSON? If so, how would I link the local JSON file as my map style into my mapbox.js code?

mapbox.js code (with faulty mapbox Studio style):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.28.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.28.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        .map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map' class='map'></div>

<style>

.legend {
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    border-radius: 3px;
    bottom: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.legend h4 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.legend div span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}

</style>

<div id='map'></div>

<div id='HVI-legend' class='legend'>
    <h4>HVI</h4>
    <div><span style='background-color: #EB6769'></span>1</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #F3B3B4'></span>0.5</div>
    <div><span style='background-color: #FCFCFF'></span>0</div>
</div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RhbWxlcm4iLCJhIjoiY2l3MnkwZ2tnMDEwejJ6anZtM240c2d3byJ9.ZTqhEH-1r0WelPq2n0rshQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/stamlern/ciwa09zej000f2pmrr8lm10ju',
    center: [-73.949, 40.71],
    zoom: 10.1
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to upload the GeoJSON file as a "dataset", rather than as a "tileset". You'll get much better performance (and won't run into the restriction you describe) if you upload it as a tileset, and style based on that.

If you really do want to add the GeoJSON file locally, use [`map.addSource`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#GeoJSONSource).